# Using a timer to update form - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, forms, timer

I want to display the status of aspects of my application on a form.

I tried adding a timer to the form. Every 10 seconds the timer runs and checks a database for a particular status, then changes elements on the form based on the status.

This works fine for changing the colour of menu items, but when I try and make an image (in)visible on the form, I get a cross-thread error.

Should I be using a timer, Backgroundworker or something else?

Does someone have a basic bit of code that will do this elegantly?

Private WithEvents tmrMain As New System.Timers.Timer(10000)

```
Private Sub frmMaster_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    tmrMain.Enabled = True
    tmrMain.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub tmrMain_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles tmrMain.Elapsed
    Dim TRunning As Boolean = True

        TRunning = BTools.CheckImportRunningStatus '' This gets the on/off status from the DB

        If TRunning Then
            miFileMYOBImport.ForeColor = Color.Red '' Change menu color
            pbMYOBDownload.Visible = True '' Make image visible
        Else
            miFileMYOBImport.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen
            pbMYOBDownload.Visible = False
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Code added is quite basic but should give you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Private Sub MakeImageVisible(ByVal control As Control, ByVal visible As Boolean)
    If control.InvokeRequired Then
        control.BeginInvoke(New Action(Of Control, Boolean)(AddressOf MakeImageVisible), control, visible)
    Else
        control.Visible = visible
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub tmrMain_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles tmrMain.Elapsed
    Dim TRunning As Boolean = True

    TRunning = BTools.CheckImportRunningStatus '' This gets the on/off status from the DB

    If TRunning Then
        miFileMYOBImport.ForeColor = Color.Red '' Change menu color
    Else
        miFileMYOBImport.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen
    End If

    MakeImageVisible(pbMYOBDownload, TRunning) ' Make image visible or invisible
End Sub
```